# dForm plugin add time picker widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use a time picker widget as part of jquery plugin dForm  .

Specifically this timepicker widget,
https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker

I read the dForm documentation but couldn't find a way to use a custom widget like the timepicker one within dForm. I am still very new to JavaScript world, so I may be overlooking some obvious things and I apologize for it.

Will someone be willing to show me how to go about doing it? Here is my jsfiddle so far

http://jsfiddle.net/nax97af6/

It isn't really doing anything besides sticking a label saying Please Pick Time.

Appreciate any pointers.

My HTML

```
<form id="myform"></form>
```

My JavaScript

```
$("#myform").dform({
  "action": "index.html",
  "method": "get",
  "html": [{
      "type": "p",
      "html": "You must login"
    }, {
      "name": "username",
      "id": "txt-username",
      "caption": "Username",
      "type": "text",
      "placeholder": "E.g. user@example.com"
    }, {
      "name": "timepicker",
      "id": "timepicker",
      "caption": "Pick Time",
      "type": "timepicker",
    }, {
      "name": "password",
      "caption": "Password",
      "type": "password"
    }, {
      "name": "ruleenabled",
      "type": "radiobuttons",
      "id": "radiobuttonalign",
      "caption": "Make rule available for use",
      "options": {
        "No": "No",
        "Yes": {
          "checked": "checked",
          "caption": "Yes"
        }
      }
    },

  ]
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ui-dform-text').timepicker({});
});
```

My CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
}

label,
input {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem on my own:

This is my dForm code

```
  {
     "name" : "Time Picker",
     "type" : "input",
     "caption" : "Park Starting At",
     "wickedpicker" : {}
  }
```

This is the script which I added:

```
 <script>
     $.dform.subscribe("wickedpicker", function(options) {
     this.timepicker(options);
     });
 </script>
```

Open to hearing about any improvements which can be made to this code.

Thank you